# How to share zfcuser across subdomain in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I have in my application installed zfcuser module and everything works fine. I configured hostname router and here my problem starts, when I log in on main domain (http://example.com) everything is ok, but when I go to any subdomain (http://test.example.com, http://anysubdomain.example.com) I'm loosing logged state and on every subdomain I have to login again. How to share login state across subdomains? In ZF1 i just set 'cookie_domain' and it works but how make it in ZF2? Of course I'm using also Bjyauthorize and I want to keep bjyauthorize guards on subdomains...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found solution, in ZfcUser Module.php I've added:

```
use Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig;
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;

public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
{
   $config = $e->getApplication()
              ->getServiceManager()
              ->get('Configuration');

   $sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
   $sessionConfig->setOptions($config['session']);
   $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
   $sessionManager->start();

   Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
}
```

and in ZfcUser module.config.php:

```
return array(
  'session' => array(
    'use_cookies' => true,
    'cookie_domain'=>'example.com',
  )
);
```

Hope it will help somebody.